# Navigation drawer toggle padding

Tags: android

I'm using appcompat v7 with the hamburger to arrow toggle.
However, I would like to add some padding on the left of the toggle.

This is my current situation :
http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2a0f712/8

This is what I would like to have :
http://nl.tinypic.com/r/v3q176/8

I've tried this :

```
findViewById(android.R.id.home).setPadding(25, 0, 15, 0);
```

But that didn't work. However, this did add padding on the right of the toggle.
I've also tried to add padding in the styles but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the action is hard-coded in layout resources. U cant change the padding. Google did this to maintain the consistency across the app  guess.

However u can define ur own icon in a drawable with ur own attributes (padding and all) and use it as an indicator by adding this line to styles.xml

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/xyz</item>
```

And the image u have shown about what u want is actually a toolbar and not an action bar. In toolbar, the icon is by default placed there.

To know more about toolbar and how to implement them, here is a link : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are familiar with styling to some extent and recommend you go that route. FYI I have not confirmed the code below as working but I think it would be close to what you want.

For res/values-14/style.xml, something like this:

```
<!-- style for Action Bar -->
<style name="MyPaddedActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
</style>
```

And then for everything 14 and below, you would use AppCompat (res/values-14/style.xml):

```
<style name="MyPaddedActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You might also ask your self why you want to do this as it goes against what Android is trying to accomplish. From a user experience you are losing a consistent look & feel to your app by modifying the location of the home indicator.